# What are sub-elements and sub-fields in iso8538 message?

Tags: iso, iso8583

I have some basic knowledge in ISO 8583 message. I have seen data-elements and parsing them. Now I came across a message like DE48 SE62 SF4. I'm curious to know about the spceification of SE and SF. I tried to find what SE and SF are. But I could only end up finding their abbreviation and could not get much information about them. Could anyone please elaborate on this? It will be of great help to me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data Element (DE) 48 used for Private Additional data in all original specifications from 1987, 1993 and 2003 years. The definition of Sub-Elements (SE) vary from one customized specification to another as well the format and structure of data inside this data element.

Without having full message dump it is not possible to detect the specification you need to follow.

Feel free to post your test ISO 8583 message here and get additional explanation or use our online service to browse message data definitions, parse the financial messages to sub-elements and sub-fields for known messages.

Answer (score 0):

The standard is quite dense and very specific.

There are two excellent starting points:

1. First dive with a good list of all the fields and events
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8583
2. The official documentation from Mastercard or Visa https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mastercard+iso+8583